# How to Fix an Archive.php That Displays All Posts?

Tags: php, loop, customization, archives, archive-template

I am currently working on developing my first large-scale WordPress powered site, and I have run into a major problem in my archive.php file. It loads all posts, rather than the categories/tags that I am looking to display.

The basic idea is to have an article-showcase bar in which the first 6 posts will be shown as thumnails, while the rest will be displayed in the normal format. The pagination then kicks in, and the user can click to see the next page of results, in which there will be the same article-showcase, but with the next page of standard posts. To do this I am using two loops, where the second one is offset by 6 posts. I had it working until last night, when I changed some things and reloaded only to have the thing start showing all of the posts on the site. I originally thought it was an issue with my query for standard posts, so I changed it, but now I can see no reason why it shouldn't work.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

    <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">

    <div id="main" class="m-all t-2of3 d-5of7 cf" role="main">

        <?php //Check to See If We Are Looking for Posts Of A Specific Category ?>
        <?php if (is_category()) {
        ?>

                <h1 class="archive-title h2">

                        <span><?php _e( ' ', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span> <?php single_cat_title(); ?>

                </h1>

        <?php //Check to See If We Are Looking for Posts With A Specific Tag ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_tag()) { ?>

                <h1 class="archive-title h2">

                        <span><?php _e( ' ', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span> <?php single_tag_title(); ?>

                </h1>

        <?php //Check to See If We Are Looking for Posts From A Specific Author ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_author()) {
                global $post;
                $author_id = $post->post_author;
        ?>
                <h1 class="archive-title h2">

                        <span><?php _e( 'Posts By ', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span> <?php the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); ?>

                </h1>

        <?php //Check to See If We Are Looking for Posts From A Specific Day ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
                <h1 class="archive-title h2">

                        <span><?php _e( 'Posted Today:', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span> <?php the_time('l, F j, Y'); ?>

                </h1>

        <?php //Check to See If We Are Looking for Posts From A Specific Month ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?>

                        <h1 class="archive-title h2">

                                <span><?php _e( 'Posted This Month:', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span> <?php the_time('F Y'); ?>

                        </h1>

        <?php //Check to See If We Are Looking for Posts From A Specific Year ?>
        <?php } elseif (is_year()) { ?>

                        <h1 class="archive-title h2">

                                <span><?php _e( 'Posts This Year:', 'bonestheme' ); ?></span> <?php the_time('Y'); ?>

                        </h1>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php //Begin Archive Article Showcase ?>
        <div id="archive-article-showcase" class="article-showcase">


            <?php

            $arcshowcaseargs = array(
            'showposts'=> 6,
            'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );

            $my_query1 = new WP_Query($arcshowcaseargs);
            if( $my_query1->have_posts() ) {
            while ($my_query1->have_posts()) : $my_query1->the_post();
            ?>



            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="archive-article-showcase-thumbnail">
                    <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) :
                    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(),'secondary-image', NULL,'square-icon-large');
                endif; ?>
                    LOL
            </a>

            <?php
            endwhile;
            }
            wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
            ?>
    </div>
    <?php //End Archive Article Showcase ?>

    <?php

            $maincaseargs = array(
            'offset = 6',
            'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );

            $my_query3 = new WP_Query($maincaseargs);
            if( $my_query3->have_posts() ) {
            while ($my_query3->have_posts()) : $my_query3->the_post();
            ?>



    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'cf' ); ?> role="article" style="position: relative; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px dashed #d4d8d8;">
        <div class="rel-box" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="thumbnail" style="display: inline-block;">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(NULL, 'main-loop') ;?>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="archive-article-holder">
                <header class="article-header">

                <h1 class="h2 entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <p class="byline vcard">

                        <p class="pureSpan">By <?php the_author(); ?></p>

                </p>

                </header>

                <footer class="article-footer cf" style="border: 0px;">
                        <p class="footer-post-date">

                                <?php printf( __( '', 'bonestheme' ) . ' <time class="updated" datetime="%1$s" pubdate>%2$s</time> ' . __(' ', 'bonestheme' ) . ' ', get_the_time('Y-m-j'), get_the_time(get_option('date_format')), get_the_author_link( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) )); ?>

                        </p>
                        <span> | </span>
                        <p class="footer-comment-count">
                                <?php comments_number( __( '<span>No</span> Comments', 'bonestheme' ), __( '<span>One</span> Comment', 'bonestheme' ), _n( '<span>%</span> Comments', '<span>%</span> Comments', get_comments_number(), 'bonestheme' ) );?>
                        </p>

                </footer>

        </div>

    </article>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php bones_page_navi(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-not-found" class="hentry cf" style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #d4d8d8;">
                    <header class="article-header">
                            <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, No Results.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></h1>
                    </header>
                    <section class="entry-content">
                            <p><?php _e( 'Try your search again.', 'bonestheme' ); ?></p>
                    </section>
                    <footer class="article-footer">

                    </footer>
            </article>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>


    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question, instead of using an external source - thanks.

Comment: So the first 6 are featured and then how many are below that in the normal format? And then what does page 2 look like? The same 6 at the top? New six? Can you explain how subsequent pages will act?

Comment: The loop should display ~10 in the standard format before initiating pagination. The in the article-showcase should stay the same when pages switch. Only the standard pages should change.

Comment: *Then, rather. I'm just having a problem with how it's fetching the posts...

Comment: I've noticed that `showposts` (now `posts_per_page`) and `caller_get_posts` (now `ignore_sticky_posts`) have both been deprecated for a while now. I'd start with that, more info: [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Also, you should use `wp_reset_postdata()` vs `wp_reset_query()`. Start with those updates and then let us know, are you using the latest WP versino 3.9.1?

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest. I have tried, and it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: Please work on your readability when you add code to your question

Comment: I don't really see how that's fair, as I went through and spent ~45 minutes writing comments telling exactly what each piece was supposed to do. It has that indentation only because the code post wouldn't let me delete the extra space.

Comment: I'm not being rude here, I was just talking about that your code goes so much out of the code block, it makes it hard to read. No harm intented here. Will post an answer now to your problem, just busy still :-)

Comment: I didn't take any offence. I was just saying that the code box is weird to a person not used to using it, and I couldn't figure out how to "back tab" to get them in a line.

Comment: No problem, I hope my edit helped though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main query that runs on archive pages are quite specific to archive pages, and this query is not replicated with a default custom query. As your code stands, your query will retrieve posts according to published date, ie from newest to oldest, and not according to archive.

**THE PROBLEM**

There are a couple of issues here that I would like to point out. @deflime already pointed out one or two things here, and I would like to repeat it for the completeness of my answer

- `showposts` and `caller_get_posts` has been depreciated long time ago. They where replaced by `posts_per_page` and `ignore_sticky_posts` respectively
- [`wp_reset_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) is used in conjuction with [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) which should **NEVER** be used. When using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), you should be using [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

The real issue here though, as I said is your custom query. My emphasis, **never use a custom query if it is not necessary**. And in this case, I can't see the necessity for a custom query. First of all, you are running two queries here, this is always problematic, as you later need to merge these queries, and this really cause headaches with pagination.

Secondly, you would need to run a complex custom query for this to work. That is why I say, keep to the main query, as your custom query basically does the same exact thing as the main query. These changes you are doing can easily been done with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). This alters the main query before it is run, so you won't have any negative impact.

**THE SOLUTION**

I would suggest to keep to the main query and use the default loop. To split your content they way you are describing it, use a counter. Count the fisrt six posts and do something, and for any other post not within the fisrt six, do something else. I would do something like this

```
<?php
$counter = 0; //Starts counter for post column lay out

    // Start the Loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$counter++; //Update the counter

    if($counter < 5){
        <---DO SOMTHING FOR FIRST SIX--->
    }else{
        <---DO SOMTHING FOR OTHER POSTS--->
    }               

endwhile;
?>
```

This way, you will not break anything. If you need custom posts per page on your archive page, like I said, use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query

```
function custom_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 'AMOUNT OF POSTS YOU WANT' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try in the morning to see if how it works.

Comment: Great, please accept my answer if it works, if not, reply and tell me where my answer is lacking. Enjoy your evening

Comment: From what I see, it looks like it will. I went back to the default file to test the main loop and it worked. So it was just my query method.

Comment: Glad it worked. Enjoy :-)